# Debugging a Visual Studio 2010 extension or addin, always gives me LoaderLock

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to write an extension for VS2010, but I get this every time:

1. Hit F5 to start debugging
2. A new instance of visual studio starts up
3. I can see a bunch of DLLs loading in the debug host while the new instance is starting
4. It then fails with a "LoaderLock".

When I continue after that, the new instance is fully functional, but there's no debugging happening at all.

The same happens when creating an addin.

Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should disable LoadLockException doing the following :

- Click *Debug/Exception...*
- Extend *Manage debugging assistant*
- Uncheck *LoaderLock* in the list

The exception should not be thrown anymore when debbugging.